# Why the global variable not works in .rb file but works in irb?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to add indentation based on how deep the block goes. I used a global variable to record the depth of block.

```
$depth = 0

def log(des, &block)
  indentation = "  " * $depth
  $depth += 1
  puts "#{indentation}Begginning the #{des} block"
  puts "#{indentation}Finished #{des} and returned: #{block.call}"
  $depth -= 1
end


log "outer block" do
  log "second level block" do
    log "third level block" do
      "I am number 3"
    end
    "I am number 2"
  end
  "I am out most!"
end
```

In terminal I tried several times `ruby file_name.rb`, it showed no indentation, it even won't `puts` the global variable out. After then I copy the code to `irb` and it worked.

Why this happened?

What's the difference when running ruby code in between these two places?

Comment: I pasted your code into a file and ran it with `ruby`, and it gave the same output as pasting the code into `irb`.

Comment: @RJHunter That's strange, originally I thought it might be some printing configurations that lead to this. But I tried using `puts` method to print out the global variable when it was changing. And it turned out that also not worked.

Comment: I had the same experience as RJHunter.  It runs the same in an file or in irb.  I wonder if you have another definition of log() in your environment that is being run instead of the one you define, somehow???

Comment: @Leonard Thank you, you found the problem. I just changed the method's name, and it works now. Would you want to make a short answer and I could mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a different definition of log() in your environment.  Changing the name of your routine to something else (say 'mylog') will test this hypothesis.